# How to Use more then one URL Schemes in IOS in .plist file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, pinterest

I am working on one project, where I need to implement Facebook sharing as well as Pinterest Sharing. Both uses URL Schemes in .plist

If I use Item 0 of URL Schemes for Facebook, Facebook sharing is working and Pinterest sharing is not working.

Also If I use Item 0 of URL Schemes for Pinterest, Pinterest only work. But not both together.

Please help how to use both together?
I have seen following function in appDelegate but how to use it?

How to set URLSchemes for Facebook and Pinterest??

Note:
I have used Social Framework for Facebook, and SDK of Pinterest

```
application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you need to check following conditions with the help of URL Scheme

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
//    NSLog(@"scheme: %@", [url scheme]);
//    NSLog(@"host: %@", [url host]);
if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"FACEBOOK_SCHEME"]) {
    return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];
}
else if([[url scheme] isEqualToString:"Pinterest_SCHEME"])
{
// Pinterest
}
return NO;
}
```

Hope it will help you..